# error stacking rasters from list in R on Linux

Tags: linux, r, stack, raster, hpc

I am having issues stacking my rasters from list before I create raster time series. When I do this directly in the R environment using sample data, it works out fine. 
The codes prior to this error are:

```
FunR<-function(r){
  ext<-raster(extent(r),nrow=1100,ncol=1100)
  crs(ext)<-crs(r)
  D<-rasterize(r,ext,field="LFRP")
  EC<-extent(-20, 60,0,30)
  D2<-extend(D,EC)
  D3<-crop(D2,extent(-18,20,2,30))
  s <- raster(nrow=600, ncol=1000,extent(-18,20,2,30))
  crs(s)<-crs(WA)
  Ds <- resample(D3, s, method='bilinear')
  crs(Ds)<-crs(WA)
  Ds
}
###Create rasters and crop
DL4<-sapply(DL3,FunR)
DL5<-stack(DL4) #(error occurs after this line)
```

However, once I send it in as a script to run on the HPC I get the following error:

```
Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: stack -> stack -> .local
```

How do I get ride of this, please? In addition, how do I get rid of files on my list that are totally `NA`? I suspect this may be an issue too.
Here's my "qsub" script:

```
#PBS -o fre8.txt
#PBS -e fren8.txt
#PBS -N FRP08_quarterly
#PBS -q high_mem
#PBS -l walltime=50:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=4
#PBS -l vmem=400gb
#PBS -m bea
#PBS -M me@...com
module load R/3.1.3
cd /scratch/aroo1
R --no-save -q -f FRPquarts.R
```

Comment: Hi everyone. Now, my script runs but is halted automatically after a few hours. How do I make R stable on the HPC, please? I now have complete codes which runperfectly on Linux but crash after a few hours running on HPC.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using the raster library in HPC linux environments will generally give output errors if the gdal module is not explicitly loaded in the session.
For instance, using slurm on a linux cluster I often have to load gdal before running scripts using:
    load gis/gdal-1.9.2

With Slurm, I have used 'module avail' to list all available modules already installed in the cluster. I am sure qsub has a very similar command. Just take note of the gdal module path/name and use the load or module load command to get it running. Now, if gdal is not available, you will have to either get the admins to install it to the cluster or write a script to do an install to your own home directory.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for replying. I have edited the codes above to reflect the qsub codes. how do I add a line for gdal please?

Comment: With Slurm, I have used 'module avail'  to list all available modules already installed in the cluster. I am sure qsub has a very similar command. Just take note of the gdal module path/name and use the load or module load command to get it running. Now, if gdal is not available, you will have to either get the admins to install it to the cluster or write a script to do an install to your own home directory.